# How can i fix this "Pods.xcodeproj"?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

[image]

I have downloaded the project from github, but failed to run the project. I have installed the cocoapods on my system, but do not know how to integrate with existing projects like that.

Comment: Did you run `$ pod install` and / or `$ pod update` after you cloned the repo?  You may need to do that.

Comment: I move to project directory by running this command:
cd /Users/Nain/k-ios-knotes/knotes
then run this:
$pod install
but i got this message:
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
Do not know what to do now, it is not working.

Comment: Don't actually type the `$`, that was just to indicate that you do this at the bash prompt.  Just do `pod install`.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I tried with both $pod install and pod install. also $pod update and pod update. But noting works for me.

Comment: Did you [install cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)?

Comment: Yes i did and my version was 0.39.0

Comment: What errors are you actually getting from Xcode then?

Comment: Are you opening the `xcprj` or `xcwkspace` file? Because it needs to be the latter.

Comment: I am opening "Knotes.xcworkspace" and i see following errors when i run the project:
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
i googled but did not find any solution that works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing this issue because some how my cocoapods were not properly installed. I was unable to run `$pod install` no pod command was working.
I have `OS X El Capitan 10.11` so i run this command `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` and after that i move to my project directory and run `pod install` and works and updated my project.